# Centos OS command to unlock domain account

Tags: centos, ssh, domain

I have CentoOS servers that are on my MS domain.  I had another admin login to one with the wrong password 3 times.  We have unlocked him on the domain but he is still locked out on that server.  What is the command to unlock him on that server because he cannot log back into that particular server? Of course, no domain account shows under that directory only local accounts. This is entry under ssh of course if that changes anything.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my own question is

```
sudo pam_tally2 --file /var/log/tallylog --user [username]  --reset
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to set him a new password?

Otherwise this might work:

```
passwd -u username
```